# How to make a link to external file line in Emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have 2 files:

1. php file with code
2. org file with docs

How to create a link to a line in php file from org file? So clicking it will move the cursor to the appropriate line in php file.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use this notation in the org mode to create a link:

```
[[/path/to/file.php::line][string-to-display]]
```

If you want the file name to be displayed, use just

```
[[/path/to/file.php::line]]
```

See *[Hyperlinks](http://orgmode.org/manual/Hyperlinks.html)* in the Org mode Info page for details and other ways to specify links.

Comment: This works, but some files (that don't have .org or .txt extensions) open in TextEdit instead of Emacs. Assuming I don't want to go and `setq auto-mode-alist` for every dot file in my home directory, how can I force an org-mode file link to open the file in Emacs?

Comment: @incandescentman I've never seen that. What files? What's TextEdit?

Comment: TextEdit is an external text editor (it's OSX's default system text editor). Example: in org-mode, I have 
`[[~/.hunspell_en_US]]` which is my user local dictionary. But when I place point on that file link and hit enter, it opens in TextEdit.

Comment: I do use a package called `open-with` that for e.g. tells .pdf files to open in an external application, but I don't see anything in my config that should affect text files. Guess I'll ask it as a new question. Thanks though!

Comment: I need to prefix it with `file:` for this to work properly. Otherwise it errors with "no match for fuzzy expression: <filename>".

Answer (score 18):

If I understand the question right you can do it automatically with two org-mode commands:

Move the point to a line in a php file and `M-x org-store-link`.

Go to an org file and `C-c C-l` or `M-x org-insert-link` and follow the instructions in the minibuffer.

You are done, click the link or `C-c C-o` when the point is on it to open the link.

I have `org-store-link` on `C-c l` and `org-insert-link` on the default `C-c C-l`. This makes the process very convenient and fast to execute.

Have fun with org-mode.

Comment: Just a comment here in case someone encounters an issue similar to mine: storing and inserting links to headlines in org files won't work correctly if there is a timestamp in the headline.

Comment: The point is to tell emacs with which software to open it. Otherwise it will open keynote files on emacs.